# How do I view systemd logs from before a journal corruption?

Tags: systemd

I had a server issue today where CPU was pegged at 100%. I had to hard-reset the server in order to bring it back up, and now I'm trying to determine the cause of the high load.

Unfortunately journalctl won't show any log information since before the reboot. I did `journalctl --verify` and it shows one corrupt file. I'm assuming this has something to do with the issue, but how do I view the log since before the corruption? I tried `journalctl --since yesterday`, and even tried since two days ago, but still no luck.

Comment: Depending on your configuration, the data might have been forwarded to a syslog, in which case it's available under `/var/log/messages` as per usual.

Comment: Kind of hard to check post-moterm for high cpu load since if there's any it's not written by default in logs. You have to look for something else that might indicate high load like an oom-killer, above average requests to a service or bad disk/filesystem. If there's users using the machine check for logged in users at that time and if they'd run anything. By default (if you're on redhat like system) logs are forwarded to rsyslog and saved to various files in /var/log/.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a relatively small log partition, and add it to `/etc/fstab` with `sync` option and `/var/log` mount path:

```
...<previos fstab lines>...
UUID=<UUID of created partition>  /var/log  ext4  rw,sync  0  0
```

This will force your system to write log directly on block device without caching writes, so log messages are written at the time they appear, and won't be discared on reboot.
But remember that the synchronous log write can be pretty IO hungry, and is not suitable for long-term use on production servers.

Answer (score 1):

## First, let's talk about corruptions (those which are detected by `journalctl --verify`).

The corruptions in the journal are unfixable in the sense that there is no redundancy in the disk format. Moreover, in some circumstances a corruption in middle of file makes its "tail" unreadable (this is another topic, really). However, `journald` never writes to an uncleanly closed journal file, so all corruptions resulting from unclean shutdowns are not harmful.

## But this is actually irrelevant.

You may look at the logs from previous boot with `journalctl -b -1`.

What's wrong with your case is that you will never see last N entries before a hardware reset, because the block I/O is normally writeback-cached. There is nothing you can do about it, except for making I/O synchronous.